# Cохранение MovieClip как изображения

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Работаю с API контакта ([процесс загрузки файлов на сервер ВКонтакте](http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)). Для метода сохранения фотки требуется: запрос должен содержать поля file1-file5, которые содержат файлы с изображениями (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF). Вопрос, как сохранить изображение из мувиклип, чтобы отправить его в запросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData();
bmpData.draw(myMovieClip);
var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(89);
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bmpData);
```

**Добавлено.**

Класс MultipartURLLoader, поищите в гугле MultipartURLLoader

```
var mll:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader(); 
mll.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadResultHandler);          
mll.addFile(byteArray, "file.jpg", "file1", 'image/jpg');
mll.load(url);
```

После аплоада нужно будет сохранить имажи в альбоме или стене

```
var parameters:Object = {aid:variables.aid, server:variables.server, photos_list:variables.photos_list, hash:variables.hash};
vkAPI.api("photos.save", parameters, fetchSaveResult, onApiRequestFail);
```

**Добавлено.**

```
private function uploadResultHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
    par = event.currentTarget.loader.data;
    saveUploadedToAlbum(parseServerAck(event.currentTarget.loader.data as String));
}
```

Comment: 2. Приложение формирует POST-запрос на полученный адрес.
Запрос должен включать поле photo, содержащее файл с изображением (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF) 

Может я не понял. Но судя по документации он только получает адрес загрузки. А как и где параметров отправить наш результат?

Comment: Окей. Завтра с утра проверю.

Comment: У БитмапДата есть 2 обязательных параметра высота и ширина, какими  их указывать для поста на стенку в ВК?

Comment: разве это требуется про посте фотки ? нигде не видел

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#BitmapData%28%29

Comment: битмап/битмапдата ширину и высоту берите у исходного мувиклипа